# Can you see Amazon Mechanical Turk requester API requests from an IAM account on the web portal of your main AWS account?

Tags: mechanicalturk, mturk

I have an AWS account, and created an IAM user that has mturk permissions. I've used it to create requests, and been able to fulfill them as worker, and access their results via the API. Great.

But I've been unable to view them on the mTurk UI, of my AWS account. i.e. when I look at Manage Batches, all the segments are empty.

I have been able to see a batch if I create requests from the web UI, but not if they originate from the API.

I suspect it may be because there is a silo between my main account and the IAM account, but how do I cross it? Or is it not possible?

Perhaps a more general question, it's not clear with the mturk UI how I would share access to requests to multiple human users either.

Thanks!